# how to set browser compatiability in jsp?

Tags: jsp, google-chrome, cross-browser, mozilla

I am developing j2e web application.

when i run my application(jsp,servlet) in firefox,it display like below image.
[image]

when i run same page in chrome, it display like below image.

[image]

My code structure is,

```
     <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
            pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
     <%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.*"%>

     <!DOCTYPE>
    or
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/transitional.dtd">

            <html>

            <head>
<style type="text/css">
body{

background-size:1024px 768px;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-image: url('styleback.jpeg');


}
</style>

</head>
            <body>
  <div id="mybox" align="left" style="display:none;">

            <form action="ModifyPlannerServlet" method="post" id="ModifyPlannerServletid">
            <div id="SearchDateErrorMsgDiv" style="color: red"></div>
           Select Date : <input type="text" name="dateofSearch" id="dateofSearch" placeholder="Enter Date Here"><br><br>

           <a href="#ListboxDisplayFromDB" id="SearchButtonn"><input type="submit"  value="Search" id="SearchButton" name="SearchButton" disabled ></a>

           </form>
</div>

<div align="center">
<form action="PlannerServlet" method="post" id="PlannerServletid"> 

            <table align="center">

                               <tr>

                                <td><label>Change Chapter</label>
</table>
</form>
</div>

<div id="AddPlannerdiv" align="center">
    <input type="button"  name ="ADDPlanner" id="ADDPlanner" value="Add Planner"  onclick="ArrayScript()" disabled>
    <input type="hidden" value="" id="selectdtext" name="selectdtext">
</div>



            </body>
            </html>
```

I have seen about browser compatibility in jsp but i dont understand how to fix this issue.

How to fix this?

Comment: its hard to tell without looking into your code, specially css, post it as well for better help

Comment: @Arvind thanks for reply. check my code now.

Comment: What's your monitor's resolution in those screenshots? It almost looks like the default zoom level is wrong for one or the other. What happens if you hit "ctrl" + "0" on both pages? do either change size?

Answer (score 1):

In CSS part you can use

```
html { 
  background: url(styleback.jpeg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```