# browser compatablity issue in j2ee web application

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, browser

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    background: url("../images/theserverside/bodyBackground.png") repeat-x scroll 0% 0% rgb(45, 70, 101);
    height: 100%;
}



#containerOuter {
    border-left: 4px solid rgb(21, 46, 72);
    border-right: 4px solid rgb(21, 46, 72);
}

#containerOuter {
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 560px;
}
#containerOuter {
    height: auto !important;
    min-height: 100%;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    background-color: red;
}

#containerInner {
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    padding-bottom: 1px;
    padding-top: 1px;
    background-color: orange;
    background: url("wood1.jpg");
    color: whitesmoke;
}

</style>

</head>
<body class="discussionsLanding">




<div id="containerOuter">






<div id="containerInner">


Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce a ligula dolor. Fusce congue elementum nulla at tempor. Nulla elit ligula, consequat sed convallis id, condimentum ac tellus. Proin volutpat, dolor id porttitor consequat, metus nulla elementum purus, ut lacinia dui turpis vel nibh.



</div>


</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Above code i used for design jsp page for my application. it looks good in Mozilla Firefox but when ever i run the above code in chrome it looks different with size and other alignments . what can i do for display content in Mozilla and chrome in same alignment and size

This my chrome result
[image]
This is my Mozilla result
[image]

How to fix this issue?

Comment: it looks the same for me

Comment: even i have this issue and i have asked question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25946021/how-to-set-browser-compatiability-in-jsp?noredirect=1#comment40622305_25946021 but no answer from anyone.

Comment: @Dunken the image you can see the difference size of the content

Comment: What's your monitor's resolution in those screenshots? It almost looks like the default zoom level is wrong for one or the other. What happens if you hit "ctrl" + "0" on both pages? do either change size?